# Clearing an s3 bucket with aws-sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've been working with the aws/s3 gem up until this point and had to switch to aws-sdk gem for this project. In the aws/s3 gem, you could get a reference to a bucket and then call:

```
bucket.clear
```

To delete everything in the bucket. How can I do this with the aws-sdk gem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can augment the [AWS::S3::Bucket](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/aws/s3/bucket.rb) class by putting a twist on the delete! method. Since classes are always open in Ruby this is pretty trivial.

```
module AWS
  class S3
    class Bucket
      def clear_objects!
        versions.each_batch { |batch| objects.delete(batch) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Would this be an instance where you'd recommend using "!" in the method name to indicate its destructiveness? A la `clear_objects!`?

Answer (score 7):

This is now supported in the aws-sdk gem.

```
bucket#clear!
```